# To get the values from backend side automatically to client side asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

Shown below is the code used in the Backend side of the asp.net C#.

```
private void ParseData(string data)
{
// Calculate the length of the string data
int dataLength = data.Length;
if (dataLength == 8)
{

}

else
{
try
{
string[] splitDelimeter = { "," };
var listofwld_data = data.Split(splitDelimeter, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
string firstvalue = listofwld_data[0].ToString();
Repno = firstvalue.Substring(1); //EXAMPLE VALUES (1001,1002,1003...) 

// FOR FINDING THE COUNTER-NO FROM THE RECEIVED DATA
Counterno = "C1";
//Counterno = C_no(listofwld_data[2], listofwld_data[4]);

string script = $@"<script>
var tokenValue = '{Repno}';
var counterValue = '{Counterno}';
UpdateTokensAndCounters(tokenValue, counterValue);
</script>";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "UpdateTokensAndCounters", script);
} 


Code used in the client side of asp.net C#
html (where to want to display)
<div class="grid-section">
<div class="grid-item">
<div class="token" runat="server" id="token1"></div>
<div class="counter" runat="server" id="counter1"></div>
</div>
</div>
the JS i have used
setInterval(function UpdateTokensAndCounters(tokenValue, counterValue) {
document.getElementById('token1').innerText = tokenValue;
document.getElementById('counter1').innerText = counterValue;
}, 1000);
```

what am expecting that, want to display the values of the backend side to client side automatically. but right now the values are not displaying after web page loaded.

Comment: To automatically display backend values on the client-side, ensure the JavaScript function UpdateTokensAndCounters is defined before use, execute it on page load using window.onload, and call it with correct arguments using clientScript.RegisterStartupScript in C# code. Also, make sure the variables Repno and Counterno are available in the frontend.

Comment: is there any other method to call the backend values to client side in every 1 seconds.

Comment: Yes , to get the backend values to the client-side every 1 second, you can use AJAX polling with JavaScript setInterval, WebSocket for real-time updates, SignalR for ASP.NET Core, Server-Sent Events (SSE) for one-way real-time communication, or push notifications for updates when the web page is inactive. You can choose the method based on your application's needs and consider the impact on server resources and network traffic.

Comment: Which of them will suitable for Waiting List Display (web application) for Hospitals, every time application must display the TOKEN and COUNTER receiving from the hospital application.

Comment: application is receiving the data from hospital through IP/PORT.

Comment: You can try AJAX to make periodic requests to the server at regular intervals and server can respond with the latest data to be displayed on the frontend. This approach is suitable for scenarios where real-time updates are not critical.

Comment: Other approach can be Server-Sent Events SSE allows the server to send data updates to the client over a single HTTP connection. It establishes a persistent connection, and the server can push updates to the client whenever new data is available. SSE is suitable when you need real-time updates but don't need bidirectional communication.

Comment: okey first i will try with the ajax request to server and let me check, any additional tips for me with the ajax request, thanks for your support

Comment: Can you provide me code of 'AJAX to make periodic requests to the server at regular intervals and server can respond with the latest data to be displayed on the frontend.'

Comment: while executing of the application one error (Backend) like "Response = 'Response' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'" happen at                                               '           JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string jsonData = serializer.Serialize(responseData);

            // Return the JSON data to the client-side script
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            Response.Write(jsonData);
            Response.End(); '

Comment: You can also try signalR jQuery library to achieve real-time updates between the backend (server-side) and the client-side jQuery SignalR library. If you want I can provide you the sample code.